# How to preserve columns ordering when creating a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, dictionary

For example, say I have computed two variables `A` and `B`, both numpy arrays.

Now I would like to make a dataframe out of them, then write to CSV, so that B goes before A. However, when I try:

```
out_df = pd.DataFrame({'B':B,'A':A})
out_df.head()
```

I see that column A has been placed to the left of column B. In some analyses, this won't matter, but I specifically want column B first, then column A in the output csv.

How do I tell pd.DataFrame to respect the ordering of the columns as I specify them?

Comment: `out_df[['B', 'A']].to_csv(...)`

Comment: @Psidom That would work, but is it possible to make `out_df` "right" in the place, so that I don't need to do something like you suggest at the `to_csv` step?

Comment: You pass the data as dictionary, which does not have order of keys. After you create a dataframe, do the `df=df[["B", "A"]]`.

Comment: pandas version 1.2.1 and pandas version 1.2.4 cannot replicate the issue: out_df has columns in order of keys in the dictionary. (Python 3.8.5)

Comment: Given the current data you have, this is the easiest way to reorder columns. But sure you can do `pd.DataFrame(list(zip(B, A)), columns=['B', 'A'])`

Comment: What is your python version? IIRC, python once didnot retain order of a dict( and we used to use OrderedDict). Upgrade your version maybe, EDIT:  okay got it its 3.6+ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6

Comment: @anky I have Python 3.6.0 and Pandas 0.20.2. It's a work setup and I may not be able to change these versions.